# How can I power this micro pump

Tags: power-supply, usb

Firstly please forgive my electrical ignorance (I'm a competent software developer but that's all).

I am hoping to power a micropump ([model M100S standard](http://www.micropumps.co.uk/TCSM100range.htm)) for a terrarium, my (possibly naïve) idea is to power it from USB, with a variable resistor to allow me to control the flow.

Ideally I'd like to be able to control the entire system from a PC:  on, off and variable flow.

However I'm aware that this may be massively complicated (an actual USB device as opposed to simply drawing power), so as a first pass I would like to get it safely drawing power over USB.

Any clues as to how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Powering a breadboard with USB](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29043/powering-a-breadboard-with-usb)

Comment: I vote not-a-duplicate -- this question has the additional twist of using a motor load (which is an inductive load) on USB. Most breadboards have more-or-less constant current load.

Comment: @BrianCarlton Agreed the difference may well be superficial and conclusion identical =)  I read that question (it was listed as related while posting this question) but he's playing with chips on a breadboard, while I want to determine if USB can provide a reliable power source for the specific pump in the link above.  Heeding jippie's advice I will probably go for the old mobile adapter for now but would like to know a bit about GPIO/Arduino/PIC too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB without logic attached can source 100mA max @ 5V. Your selected pump will not work. If you select a type that requires < 100mA and accepts 5V, you'll have the problem that your pump motor will induce EMI on the 5V lines that run directly into your PC. You'll need some filtering too, otherwise your PC will probably start to do wierd things every now an then.

I'd go for a mains adapter of an old mobile phone you're no longer using.

Comment: Thanks for the warnings - I guess this may be easier via some GPIO board?

Comment: That would be a decent option, and run the pump from a separate power supply. But it does require some basic understanding of electronics.

Comment: So an old phone adapter matching the pumps DCV 3 - 4.5, 280 - 420 mA will be safe? provided I can solder and insulate wires =)

Comment: That'd be a good start. Mind you a pump with a higher voltage (say 9-12VDC) and lower current is somewhat easier to vary with beginners grade electronics.

Comment: Think I'll go with the mobile charger for now.  Thanks Jippie